# Bacteria data in Python: compare values per group within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Question! I'm a little bit stuck with my data in Python. Here is my problem:

I have data about 40 bacteria in different samples in a human body. The participants were sampled ranging from 2 to 12 times. There were 3 different sampling methods used, say method1, method2, method3.
So the data looks like this:

```
ID | method | bacteria1 | bacteria2 | bacteria3 | bacteria4 ....
1  |   1    |     0     |      1    |      0    |     1
1  |   2    |     0     |      1    |      0    |     0
1  |   3    |     0     |      1    |      0    |     0
1  |   2    |     1     |      1    |      0    |     0
2  |   3    |     1     |      0    |      0    |     0
2  |   2    |     0     |      0    |      0    |     0
3  |   3    |     0     |      0    |      1    |     0
3  |   1    |     0     |      0    |      0    |     0
```

Here's what I need, per participant (thus grouped by ID), I need to find out if there is a bacteria found (0 = not present, 1 = present) with method 3 and if that bacteria is also present with method 1 and/or 2. If that is the case, the test is positive!

So in my mind what I need is to get the results like this:

```
    ID | method | bacteria1 | bacteria2 | count True|count False
     1  |   1    |   False  |    True   |      1    |     1
     1  |   2    |   False  |    True   |      1    |     1
     1  |   3    |     0    |      1    |      0    |     0
     1  |   2    |   False  |    True   |      1    |     1
     
     2  |   3    |     1    |      0    |      0    |     0
     2  |   2    |   False  |     False |      0    |     2

     3  |   3    |     0    |      0    |      0    |     0
     3  |   1    |   False  |     False |      0    |     2
```

So far I only managed to split the data per group and check if the 3rd method was used or not

```
df = df.groupby(['ID', 'method'])

for name, group in df:
    print('ID: ' + str(name))
    x = group['method']==3
    print("\n")
```

Can anyone get me going again?

Thank you so much in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use my solution, you'll need to take the numbers out of your column names. bacteria1 needs to be called bacteria_one etc. Once that is done, you can use the .query function in the pandas DataFrame class. The code would look something like this;

```
df.query(
"method == 3"
).query(
"bacteria_one == 1"
"or bacteria_two == 1"
"or bacteria_three == 1"
)
```

This will return results where any of the three bacteria has a value of 1 and the method is three. You can do the same with the other methods and you'd have a df for each method only containing values for 1 in any bacteria column. You also mentioned wanting values of True instead of 1 and values of False instead of 0. That code would look like this;

```
df['bacteria_one'].replace([0, 1], [False, True])
```

I may have misunderstood your query, so I want to add this. If what you really want is to remove results where no bacteria column has a value of 0, that query would look like this.

```
df.query(
"bacteria_one != 0"
"or bacteria_two != 0"
"or bacteria_three != 0"
)
```

Comment: thank you a lot! Your answer really helps. The only issue is, as output I still get participants that were not tested with method 3. So it seems that the argument "method == 3" doesn't work for me. What do you think?

Comment: Ok, i'll edit my answer to include a solution that definitely works. Basically just make them into two querys being applied after another on the original object. Total monkey-patch solution, but whatever.